# Is there a way in R to distribute geocoordinates around a starting point?

Tags: r

Hey Guys for my Bachelor Thesis I'm looking for a method to distribute geocoordinates around a starting point.

I want to generate the address data of 100 employees of a fictitious company.The company location is the starting point. Then I want to distribute the addresses/coordinates around the starting point after static surveys for the distance from the employee to the employer in Germany.

The distributions are for example:
under 5km : 26.6%
5-10km: 21.7%
10 - 25km: 29.1%

So I want to distribute 26.6% of the employees in a 5km radius, randomly, around my company location of (49.0,12.1).

and so on...

Is there a method/package for this?

So far I use rgeo, but there, as far as I know, I can distribute coordinates only within a fixed boundary, but not around a starting point.

Comment: "I can distribute coordinates only within a fixed boundary, but not around a starting point." -- if you have a starting point and radius, you can create a shape (i would start with `buffer` of 5 km radius), then distribute the 26.6% points within this buffer.

Comment: What distribution do you want for your locations?  Using what frame of reference?  Do you need to take acount of geospatial issues like curvature of the earth? For a very simple implementation, use polar co-ordinates: generate random angles between 0 and 2*pi.  Generate a random distance.  Convert to Cartesian.  "Add" your factory location.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko How can I apply the buffer method to my case? I am new to R and have tried to read up on it in other posts here, but didn't quite understand how to implement it.

Comment: @Limey The distribution of the points in the radius of 5km should be random in some way. Do I need to have a frame? If yes I would say a radius of 100km. A simple implementation is fully ok.

Comment: If you are not concerned with true uniformity, you can randomize via polar: `geosphere::destPoint(p,b,d)` where `p` is your starting point, the bearing `b <- runif(n, 0, 360)`, and the distance (meters) `d <- runif(n, 0, 5000)`. It's actually mathematically feasible to bias that `d` away from center a bit to mimic uniform (cartesian) distribution.

Comment: @FelixMurr, see my answer

Comment: @r2evans I will try it and I'm not concerned with true uniformity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `cp` is company starting point, then something like:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.2, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
cp <- st_sfc(st_point(x = c(362665, 362017)), crs = 2180)
buffer_size <- 5000
buffer <- st_buffer(cp, buffer_size ) 

samples <- st_sample(buffer, 26)

plot(buffer)
plot(cp, add = T, pch = 22)
plot(samples, add=T, pch = 18)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is very helpful and should work, how would the implementation then look for a radius of 5000-10000? Just change the buffer size to 5000-10000?
And how can I save the 26 created coordinates in a list for example? Sorry for all the questions, have very little basic knowledge in R and trying to improve.

Until now I have saved my coordinates in latitudes and longitudes would that be possible here again?

Comment: You can `save(samples, file="samples.dat")` and then `load("samples.dat")`, you can `view(samples)`, etc. As in fact `samples` is a list of length 26, you can access the items in the list like `samples[10]` to see 10th sample.
And yes, you can change the buffer size as you wish, however please remember, that it will be distributed within the whole buffer. So, if you wish a geometry between buffer = 10 km and buffer = 5 km (kind of donut), then you can use st_difference(buffer10k, buffer5k). Please be aware, that `buffer` uses the same units as used CRS.

Comment: Thanks that clarified a lot of things. I will try it.